# PHP Jquery ajax call not increment value of variable in ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to increment value of variable by one in ajax call success. I have used following script but not increment value of variable, It's always return defined value.

```
jQuery(".custom_product_box_add").click(function(e){
        var product_id =jQuery(this).attr('data-product_id');
        var product_qty =jQuery(this).attr('data-quantity');
        var product_box_id =jQuery(this).attr('product_box_id');
        var variation_id =jQuery(this).attr('variation_id');
        var qty_value = jQuery(this).attr("currentQty");
        var inputQtyNumber =jQuery(this).parent().prev().val(qty_value)

       var parent = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');

          var data = {
            action: 'woocommerce_custom_ajax_add_to_cart',
            product_id: product_id,
            product_sku: '',
            quantity: product_qty,
            product_box_id:product_box_id,
            variation_id: variation_id
        };

    var limit=0;

        jQuery.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            url:veh_app_script.ajaxurl,
            data: data,

            beforeSend: function (response) {
               jQuery("#loading").show();
            },
            complete: function (response) {
              jQuery("#loading").hide();
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
                if( response.error != 'undefined' && response.error ){
                      return true;
                 } else {                  
                     setTimeout(function() {

                        var jsonRsponse =response.data;
                        console.log(JSON.parse(response.data_product_string));
                      //  return false;
                        var html = '';
                          html +='<div class="row">';

                          jQuery.each(jsonRsponse,function(key,value){
                              html +='<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 mb_20">';
                              html +='<image width="300" height="300" src='+ value.image[0] + '>';
                              html +='<p class="qty_value">'+ value.qty + '</p>';
                              html +='</div>';

                          });
                         html +='</div>';
                         jQuery('.cart_product').html(html);


                    }, 2000);



                  }

                  limit = parseInt(limit) + 1; // First Way
limit++ // Second way

                  console.log('limit'+ limit  );

            }

        });

        return false;
    });
```

I have tried to increment `limit` variable value by one using following ways but not value increment by `1`

```
1 ) limit++


 2 ) limit = parseInt(limit) + 1;
```

It's always return `0` value of limit variable
 Please anyone help me what i have missed in code.

Comment: Do you mean that console.log output is alway 'limit1'?

Comment: Yes , limit value is output always return 0 not increment value by 1.

Answer (score 0):

try put

```
var limit=0;
```

outside the function

```
jQuery(".custom_product_box_add").click(function(e){...}
```

Every time you click limit get zero, but there is no other error in the code that make limit not increment

The callback success is called without errors?

Comment: I mentioned in my question that i want increment value in ajax call success.